# Why does my program go over the gmail api pull quota?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api

I've set up the gmail api so I can pull the latest 5 messages from my inbox every 10 seconds. Here's my code:

```
gmail.users.messages.list(
    { auth: auth, userId: 'me', maxResults: 5 },
    function(err, response) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err)
        return
      }
      console.log('+ 5, Listing Messages')
      response.data.messages.forEach(message => {
        console.log('Got message id: ' + message['id'])
        const id = message['id']
        gmail.users.messages.get({ auth: auth, userId: 'me', id: id }, function(
          err,
          response
        ) {
          if (err) {
            console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err)
            return
          }
          console.log('+ 5 Getting message')
          const fromHeader = response['data'].payload.headers.filter(
            header => header.name === 'From'
          )[0]
          if (fromHeader.value.includes('amarciniak@bcit.ca')) {
            response.data.payload.parts.forEach(part => {
              if (
                part.filename !== '' &&
                part.mimeType ===
                  'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
              ) {
                console.log('For Each Part')
                gmail.users.messages.attachments.get(
                  {
                    userId: 'me',
                    messageId: id,
                    id: part.body.attachmentId,
                  },
                  (err, { data }) => {
                    if (err) {
                      return console.log('Error getting attachment: ' + err)
                    }
                    console.log('+ 5 Getting attachment')
                    const hash = crypto
                      .createHash('md5')
                      .update(data['data'])
                      .digest('hex')
                    const newFileName = `${fileFolderPath}/${hash}_${part.filename}`
                    const filesInFolder = fs.readdirSync(fileFolderPath)
                    if (!filesInFolder.includes(`${hash}_${part.filename}`)) {
                      fs.writeFile(
                        newFileName,
                        data['data'],
                        { encoding: 'base64' },
                        err => {
                          if (err) {
                            console.log(err)
                          } else {
                            console.log(`Wrote File: ${newFileName}`)
                          }
                        }
                      )
                    } else {
                      console.log(
                        `No changes detected. File: ${newFileName} is already present in folder. `
                      )
                    }
                  }
                )
              }
            })
          }
        })
      })
    }
  )
}
```

I'm getting a list of messages from gmail, then for all 5 messages, I get the individual messages, then for each message I get payload parts which for each part I get the attachment and do something with it. Each of my get requests uses 5 'quota' points. From the gmail api docs, the limit is 250 /second. In this code snippet I don't see how I am possibly using over 250 quota points per second. At most I'm using 5 * 5 * 5 or so. so Like 125 points. Is it rate limiting me because these requests happen so quickly one after another than it's 125 points per 100ms which really equals 1250 points/second ? Is that how it works? Or is my code running way more frequently than I think it is?

Comment: Polling every 10 seconds? You really should consider something like https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push.

Comment: It may be worth looking at https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota#concurrent_requests, which says there is a limit to the number of concurrent requests. You are dispatching  5 `get` requests virtually simultaneously, plus more for any attachments found. You should probably do your `gets` one after the other: ensure one request is done before starting the next one (using an async management library, maybe? https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#eachLimit)

Comment: Good ideas. I implemented push now and it's alright for now. apsillers I will also take into account what you say about waiting for each request to finish before coming back.